# Preview and Log Conflicts/Warnings for TFS Get

Tags: file, tfs, get

I want to preview the files I will get with TFS first, and if there are any warnings/conflicts I will tell not to get latest. I tried this:

`tf get c:\MyWorkspace /all /preview /recursive /noprompt >C:\TFSResults\results.txt`

But it does log replacing ones to the file, and the warnings/conflicts to the command prompt window.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can get a preview of a get with the PowerShell snapin from TFS PowerToys (you'll need a custom install of the PowerToys, it is not installed by default).

Once the snapin is loaded (`Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell`) then you can use

```
Update-TfsWorkspace -WhatIf
```

Comment: +1 for good info about both tfpt *and* the powershell -whatif flag.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
tf get c:\MyWorkspace /all /preview /recursive /noprompt \
  >C:\TFSResults\results.txt 2>&1
```

`2&>1` takes the stderr output and includes it in stdout.